# feign request microservice using domain url

Tags: spring-cloud

I am invoking microservice api using feign like this now:

```
Response<List<AppResponse>> apps = appController.getApps();
```

And this is server side:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/app")
@FeignClient(name = "soa-service")
public interface IAppController {

    @GetMapping(value = "/list")
    Response<List<AppResponse>> getApps();
}
```

Because the client side and server side registerd to eureka(the eureka could find the internal registed ip address),the invoke works fine.My question is : when the client and server not in one network(maybe the client not registed to eureka and deploy to external net). Is it possible to invoke microservice using domain url like "`www.api.example.com/app/list`"?

ps:I know one solution to change my invoke using okhttpclient,but the problem is: I must change all old feign invoke to new okhttp rest invoke.

Comment: You can configure ribbon to go to a specific url without having to change any code at all

Answer (score 1):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/app")
@FeignClient(name = "soa-service",  url = "http://www.api.example.com/app/list")
public interface IAppController {

    @GetMapping(value = "/list")
    Response<List<AppResponse>> getApps();
}
```

Comment: is this change other microservice invoke?